# How many RNN units are needed for tasks involving sequences?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, recurrent-neural-network

I am training an RNN on the following task: Given a sequence of thirty words, and then classify the sequence into binary class.

Is there a benefit to having more than 30 cells (LSTM, GRU or plain RNN) in my network?
I've seen many examples online where similar networks are trained with multiple layers that each have 100 cells, but this does not make sense to me.
How does it help to have more cells than the length of the sequence? (in my case this length is 30)

I'm confused because from my understanding, each cell takes in two inputs
1. A new element of the sequence
2. The output from the previous cell
So after 30 cells, there will be no new sequence elements to input into the cell. Each cell will just be processing the output of the previous cell (receiving no new info).

I am using LSTM cells for this task (however, I'm guessing the actual type of RNN cell used is irrelevant).

**When GRU units are same as my sequence length**

```
visible = Input(shape=(30,))
print(np.shape(visible ))
embed=Embedding(vocab_size,2)(visible)
print(np.shape(embed ))
x2=keras.layers.GRU(30, return_sequences=True)(embed)
print(np.shape(x2))
```

shapes:

`(?, 30)`

`(?, 30, 2)`

`(?, ?, 30)`

**When GRU units are not the same as my sequence length**

```
visible = Input(shape=(30,))
print(np.shape(visible ))
embed=Embedding(vocab_size,2)(visible)
print(np.shape(embed ))
x2=keras.layers.GRU(250, return_sequences=True)(embed)
print(np.shape(x2))
```

shapes:

`(?, 30)`

`(?, 30, 2)`

`(?, ?, 250)`

How does the shape changes from `(?, 30, 2)` to `(?, ?, 250)` or to `(?, ?, 30)` even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some reading on the RNN equations and the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/). The first argument to the GRU initializer is **not** the number of cells that you are using, but rather the dimensionality of the hidden state (or, in Keras' awkward terminology, the *units*).

The whole point of using recurrent layers is that you will be folding over your sequence by applying the same function over and over, and this function is materialized by a single* RNN cell-- if each item of your sequence was processed by a different cell, there wouldn't be any recurrence in there.

To make things clearer, an RNN implements a function f: (x,h) → h. You give it the first item of your sequence, x<sub>0</sub> and some pre-initialized h<sub>-1</sub>, it gives you back h<sub>0</sub>. You can then give the **same** cell x<sub>1</sub> and h<sub>0</sub> and it will give you h<sub>1</sub>, and so on and so forth. Now the argument you are toying with simply adjusts the size of the hidden vector space; you will still be getting as many h vectors as you were getting before (== your input sequence length), but now each of these h vectors lives in ℝ<sup>250</sup> rather than ℝ<sup>30</sup>.

* In the case of a shallow RNN

Comment: This means that h vectors will  and should always be equal to the sequence length. The unit parameter in keras only changes the dimensionality of each of these h vectors.

Comment: Yes, exactly, at least in your current setup :)

Comment: In this case then, "h" is the output or a hidden state value?

Comment: Both. What an RNN emits to the world **is** its hidden state. If you want to perform another transformation to get a new vector space out of h, you can create another transformation g: h → y and apply it on each of the hidden states. This is useful, for instance, when you have a sequence labeling problem. Instead of constraining h to be of the same dimensionality as the number of your output classes, you instead apply g on the hidden states [h0, h1, ... hN] and get a sequence Y = [y1, y2, ... yN].